# Hyper-V VLAN with static IP

Tags: windows, hyper-v, vlan, static-ip, hadoop

Trying to setup/simulate Hadoop cluster locally via multiple (hyper-v) VMs.

I'm using hortonworks sandbox image for hyper-v which runs centos linux.

I can hit the vm, if I use an internal switch and then setup connection from adapter to this vm, and assigning the switch a static ip.

That's ok if I were just connecting from host, but not so great when the other vm also wants to talk to it. Plus I can't share connection with more than 1 switch (or can I?)

If I were to use an external switch for the hadoop node, I can ping it from host machine, but not the other vm and worse, the Hue GUI is unreachable from port 80, from the host.

Any thought on what would be the correct topology?

Comment: What does this have to do with VLAN's?

Comment: Honestly, I don't really know. I just need static IP and the ability for the VMs to talk to each other. And presumably I'd need them both on the same VLAN as that seems to be the only thing that allows the to talk to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The Hyper-V machine that I've configured uses an External Virtual Switch that has a dynamic IP, but only when the box is initially brought up by "vagrant up" - if I destroy the box and remake, I get a new IP, but until then, it stays the same.

Setting it up like this gives my host machine, and the VM internet access, and I can hit my vm from my host to view vhosts that are on there.

If I can provide any more information, let me know.

Comment: Are you using the sandbox ? Sure any tip provided would be good. Thanks.

Comment: no, the box that I use for hyper v is "hashicorp/precise64" - then I have just configured the box myself using bash scripts